# How to use django-haystack autocomplete via django-autocomplete-light

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to implement django-haystack autocomplete via django-autocomplete-light in django admin. I am using django=1.9.6, django-haystack-2.4.1, django-autocomplete-light=3.1.5. I gone through the example given in django-autocomplete-light tutorial and was able to implement it successfully. For foreign key fields it builds the queryset and return the objects.

Now in order to get results from haystack i need to change the get_queryset method to return the queryset from haystack. I believe this can be achieved by
`qs = SearchQuerySet().models(Location)`. Am i going into right direction? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.